# Hyper-V 2016 Teaming: 1 Gbps instead of 2 with Dynamic LACP?

Tags: hyper-v, lacp, network-teaming, hyper-v-server-2016, ubiquiti

I want to create a **Teaming** over both physical NICs to double the power of the virtual LAN (vLAN) on my Microsoft **Hyper-V Core 2016** Testserver.

In the "Server Manager" dialog I can create multiple types of teaming:

- Switch Independent (Teaming only on the Windows Server)

  - Failover: Just as a failover if one NIC goes down: *>>Not what I need*
  - Address Hash: Outbound Load Balancer: *>>No, I want both*
  - Hyper-V Port: Out+Inbound Load Balancer for Hyper-V. *>>Yes, but the maximum passthrough will be the maximum from one NIC (In my example = 1Gbps)*
- Switch Dependent: LACP (Configured on the managed switch)

  - Address Hash: (see above)
  - Hyper-V Port: (see above)
  - Dynamic: *>>That's what I want to use*

I configure the Teaming with LACP + Dynamic on the Windows Server. Then, on my physical switch ([UniFi Switch 24 POE-250W](https://www.ubnt.com/unifi-switching/unifi-switch-poe/)), I created a "Link Aggregation" over those two physical ports. All works fine.
After that I created a virtual Switch and assigned the teamed Nics (here: Microsoft Network Adapter Multiplexor Driver) as external network and also allow management operation system to share this network adapter (to see the vSwitch/vLan on the Hyper-V Host).

Now when I refresh the NIC-Teaming dialog, the vSwitch/vLan network also apears as option. But showing me just 1 Gbps instead of 2 in the speed-column?

[image: NIC Teaming]

**My Questions:**

1. Do I miss something? Did I something wrong?
2. Is this just wrong on the dialog? How can I check if I have 2 Gbps?
3. Should I change my configuration back to "Switch Indipendent" with "Hyper-V Port"? There I saw "2 Gbps" on the vSwitch/vLan. But each vServer will have max. 1 Gbps.